# Nodemailer - Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 216.58.221.36:587

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I have an api which sends email when a user submits data on the frontend. I can't get the nodemailer sendmail to work.

nodemailer.js -

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

async function sendmail(data) {
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "www.google.com",
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
      user: <my email>,
      pass: <password>,
    },
  });

  await transporter.sendMail(
    {
      from: data.email,
      to: <my email>, 
      subject: "CEWA Feedback", 
      text: data.message,
      html: "<b>Hello world?</b>",
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
}

module.exports = sendmail;
```

When this function runs I get this error in the console -

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 216.58.221.36:587
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '216.58.221.36',
  port: 587,
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

Any idea what's going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

can you try adding tls config to the transporter object

```
     let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com', 

        auth: {
          user: <my email>,
          pass: <password>,
        },
        tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false}
      });
```

Comment: Are you sure host is google.com? As service name is different for gmail.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Should I keep the default host `smtp.ethereal.email` ?

Comment: Updated the answer for using gmail service

Comment: `Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted` I get this error now